# Refactoring <link> tag in template html to styleUrls

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to refactor a Component, which links stylesheets in it's html template into using the styleUrls instead.

The linked template has an include alike;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I've refactored this into;

```
styleUrls: [
    'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'
],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

I can confirm the stylesheet is loaded, it is however loaded as an inline style instead of via the link tag, as such references as;

```
src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');
```

Do not point to;

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0
```

But rather to;

```
http://localhost:9000/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0
```

How would I go about refactoring the html template to using styleUrls, while keeping the relative references?

Comment: That's interesting. But honestly I don't think is there, or will ever be something builtin to fix this issue. So your best option is just to put it in your HTML header.

Comment: i think usefull for this link your works follow the link   https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/

Comment: In term of optimization and to resolve your issue, wouldn't it be a better idea to get the repo as a component in your project then don't call it from the external "maxcdn..." etc?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to find around this was [mentioned here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2991#issuecomment-120704992) in subsequent comments.

You have to create a custom UrlResolver. [Here is a test](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4342a1eb7b1d9c6f44f49ab15f325ff326dbcaaa/modules/angular2_material/test/button_spec.ts#L34) on the Angular2 Material repo where they implement a custom url resolver. Relevant sections below.

```
import {TestUrlResolver} from './test_url_resolver';
import {..., bind} from 'angular2/core';

bind(UrlResolver)
    .toValue(new TestUrlResolver());
```

Here is the TypeScript version of the [`TestUrlResolver`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4342a1eb7b1d9c6f44f49ab15f325ff326dbcaaa/modules/angular2_material/test/test_url_resolver.ts) (the other version is in Dart):

```
import {UrlResolver} from 'angular2/src/core/compiler/url_resolver';

export class TestUrlResolver extends UrlResolver {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  resolve(baseUrl: string, url: string): string {
    // The standard UrlResolver looks for "package:" templateUrls in
    // node_modules, however in our repo we host material widgets at the root.
    if (url.startsWith('package:angular2_material/')) {
      return '/base/dist/js/dev/es5/' + url.substring(8);
    }
    return super.resolve(baseUrl, url);
  }
}
```